# How can I put an object into a MB queue from an external Java application?

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I am pretty new in **WSO2 ESB** and in **WSO2 MB**.

I have the following problem: My WSO2 ESB application use a MB queue named **transferQueue**.

My doubt is: can I put an object in this queue from an external Java application? Is it a standard JMS queue? Can I access to it from outside the ESB application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, messages can be sent to the Queue from an external Java application. 
WSO2 MB support JMS standard
Yes, it can be accessed outside the ESB / MB system.

For sample code to send messages, please refer the below one.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Sending+and+Receiving+Messages+Using+Queues#4aa66b16f63b4197b4f33a972e9ed044